# Get product attribute value in new_grid.phtml magento

Tags: magento, magento2

I have problem with getting attribute value in new_grid.phtml. If i make it like this:

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct()
echo $_product->getData('attr_name') ?>
```

Page generating to this place, and after just blank page.

Please show me other option, or maybe i have mistakes in my code.

Here is the place in new_grid.phtml:

```
<div class="product-img-block">
<a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product-item-photo">
<?php echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml(); ?>

/* my code: */
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct() ?>
<img src="<?php echo $_product->getData('attr_name') ?>" />
</a>
```

**it is code from custom_home.xml**

```
<container name="header.container" as="header_container" label="Page Header Container"  htmlTag="header" htmlClass="page-header" before="main.content"/>
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_file" template="Magento_Theme::html/front-slider.phtml" before="main.content"/>

<container name="main.content" htmlTag="main" htmlId="maincontent" htmlClass="page-main">
<container name="columns.top" label="Before Main Columns"/>

<container name="columns" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="columns">
                <container name="main" label="Main Content Container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="column main"/>
            </container>
</container>
```

**In front-slider.phtml i get the new_grid.phtml by code:**

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget")->setDisplayType("all_products")->setProductsCount("6")->setTemplate("product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
```

### Errors for TBI answer:

> 1 exception(s):
>   Exception 0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Area code is already set
>
> Exception 0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Area code is already set
>   0 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/app/design/frontend/central/central-theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml(52): Magento\Framework\App\State->setAreaCode('frontend')
>   1 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/chroot/home/au...')
>   2 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget\Interceptor), '/chroot/home/au...', Array)
>   3 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/Widget/NewWidget/Interceptor.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/chroot/home/au...')
>   4 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget\Interceptor->fetchView('/chroot/home/au...')
>   5 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
>   6 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Catalog/Block/Product/Widget/NewWidget/Interceptor.php(830): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
>   7 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/app/design/frontend/central/central-theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/front-slider.phtml(81): Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget\Interceptor->toHtml()
>   8 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/chroot/home/au...')
>   9 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(255): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template), '/chroot/home/au...', Array)
>   10 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php(279): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('/chroot/home/au...')
>   11 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(659): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
>   12 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(542): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
>   13 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(518): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('test_file')
>   14 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('test_file')
>   15 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('test_file')
>   16 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('test_file', true)
>   17 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('test_file')
>   18 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper')
>   19 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
>   20 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
>   21 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', true)
>   22 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(569): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper')
>   23 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(520): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root')
>   24 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
>   25 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(472): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
>   26 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
>   27 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(938): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
>   28 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(146): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
>   29 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(494): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getOutput', Array, Array)
>   30 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Page.php(243): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
>   31 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Result/Layout.php(164): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   32 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   33 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callParent('renderResult', Array)
>   34 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-varnish-...')
>   35 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/VarnishPlugin.php(74): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   36 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(67): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\VarnishPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   37 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\Framewo...', 'renderResult', Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Array, 'result-builtin-...')
>   38 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/Controller/Result/BuiltinPlugin.php(67): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   39 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\Controller\Result\BuiltinPlugin->aroundRenderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   40 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php(130): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->___callPlugins('renderResult', Array, Array)
>   41 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(139): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
>   42 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
>   43 /chroot/home/host/domain.com/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
>   44 {main}

On this code:

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$_product= $registry->registry('current_product');
$attribute_code = 'attr_name';
echo  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)-
>getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adaptive this code to yours

```
    @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Widget\NewWidget 
    if ($exist = ($block->getProductCollection() 
    && $block->getProductCollection()->getSize())) 
    {
        $items = $block->getProductCollection()->getItems();
    }
    <?php foreach ($items as $_item): ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $_item->getData("nameofattribute") ?>" />
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

If you dont know name of attribute you may use $_item->getData() and get all of list data for current item.

Answer (score 0):

First, please verify if you have added your custom attribute in proper attribute set and assigned that attribute set to product for which you are adding this code and then finally use below code to get its value.

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
//$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
$_product= $registry->registry('current_product');
$attribute_code = 'attr_name';
echo  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes my products are in default attr set, and you code get:  Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: _product in /chroot/home/autospar/domain.com/html/app/design/frontend/central/central-theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml on line 50

Comment: I have updated the code above, please check once. Its should solve your problem
Thanks

Comment: In comments i cant show you all, i had update question: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Area code is already set

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Area code is already set

Answer (score 0):

```
getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_item);
?>
```

Comment: How i can get one of attr? Like this: <?php 
$attribute_code = 'attr_name';
echo  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
?>

Answer (score 0):

```
$_product = $block->getProduct();
print_r($_product->getData);
```

First you need to check for product data available or not if you got proper array then you just need to call product attribute from below code.

```
echo  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('ATTRIBUTE_CODE')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Comment: When i am tring to check by your code "$_product = $block->getProduct();
print_r($_product->getData);" i get this: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /chroot/home/autospar/domain.com/html/app/design/frontend/central/central-theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml on line 50

Answer (score 0):

```
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product = $productModel->load(42); // Add your product ID
$attribute_code = 'attr_name'; // Add your attribute name
echo  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

As per your comment above please try this just change product id and attribute code as i have mention above

Comment: Page generating to this place, and after just blank page, and page lost styles.

Answer (score 0):

I feel product object not available in your code. Product object only on product view page in current product. On other page you have to create.

Comment: On other page you have to create. - How?

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with a custom attribute in my own grid.phtml file. After a long time, I realised there is an attribute setting "use in product-isting" which was set to "No". Make sure this is set to yes.